Local env not pointing to local JS package
I have a local Vue app that references one of my own packages. I want to make some changes to my package and then debug it locally using my app.
I've updated the files in question and packed it up using npm pack
I've confirmed that the changes are present in the .tgz file.
I've pointed the package-lock.json file  to the local .tgz rather than the npm repository.
I've then run the npm install on my app. No errors. However, my changes aren't appearing, confirmed by looking browser dev tools. In the node_modules copy, my changes are not present.
I've tried (installing after each attempt):

checking there are no other definitions for the same package
recreating the tgz
deleting my package files in node_modules
deleting the entire node_modules directory

I am uncertain how it's getting the remote version from NPM if it's explicitly pointed to the local files:
resolved: "file:../../elevuetor-js-0.0.5.tgz"

Most likely, I'm missing a step in the install for a local file, but I can't find my mistake.
